# How can I represent integer intervals in Java?

Tags: java

We all know about intervals in mathematics (e.g -4 < x < 3).

How can I represent these mathematic intervals in Java, e.g, the numbers between -4 and 3 (-4, -3, ..., 2, 3 etc)?

Comment: How you want to use these intervals?

Comment: @Mat Sorry , What do you mean?

Comment: An interval is just a pair of numbers. What do you want to do with it? The "numbers between" can be found with any type of loop construct (for/while/...)

Comment: @Mat Aha, As Bozho said using IntRange is the best way to get an intervals number , I just need a range of number . That's all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check apache commons-lang [`IntRange`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html). So, if you want to check if a number is in a given interval (range), you do:

```
IntRange range = new IntRange(-4, 3);
if (range.contains(x)) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: why don't they stick stuff like this in core java

Answer (score 4):

You simply have to separate `-4 < x < 3` into `-4 < x` and `x < 3`, like this:

```
if (-4 < x && x < 3)
{
. . .
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea too , Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Google Guava also has a Range class (https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) that may work for you.