# Compare and sort String which have number and special characters

Tags: java

I have a list of String that I need to sort (see below).

- "< 5 ha"
- ">= 10 ha to < 20 ha"
- ">= 20 ha to < 50 ha"
- ">= 5 ha to < 10 ha"
- ">= 50 Ha"

Looks simple but until now, I didn't find an easy way to do it.
The Element class have just a property of type String named code.
The Java code is just below, any idea ?

```
    public class SortingListComparator {
      private static List<Element> testList;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         initList();
         Collections.sort(testList, new ElementComparator());

         for (Element elem : testList) {
            System.out.println("Code of element : " + elem.getCode());
         }
      }

    private static void initList() {
        testList = new ArrayList<Element>();

        Element elem1 = new Element("< 5 ha");
        Element elem2 = new Element(">= 10 ha to < 20 ha");
        Element elem3 = new Element(">= 20 ha to < 50 ha");
        Element elem4 = new Element(">= 5 ha to < 10 ha");
        Element elem5 = new Element(">= 50 Ha");

        testList.add(elem1);
        testList.add(elem2);
        testList.add(elem3);
        testList.add(elem4);
        testList.add(elem5);
    }

    public static class ElementComparator implements Comparator<Element> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Element o1, Element o2) {
            return o1.getCode().compareTo(o2.getCode());
        }   
    }    
  }
```

Comment: First of all we have to come up with the rules defining if one particular record is going before or after another particular record.

Comment: The record with the String ">= 5 ha to < 10 ha" should come just after the one with the value equals to "< 5 ha" (in second position in the list)

Answer (score 2):

The real answer here: step back - to create *helpful* abstractions.

You should not look at your problems as "string" sorting. You see, these strings represent **interval** (or range) information.

Meaning: although it might look like "more work" you should consider *modeling* these aspects. In other words:

- create a class that represents (mathematical) intervals
- create code that parses a string like " < 5 ha" into an interval object
- then sort interval objects

Instead of creating your own class, you might also look into 3rd party libraries, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368682/how-can-i-represent-integer-intervals-in-java).

The point is: your strings contain *very special* information. And the whole idea of good OOP is to represent this "the best way" within your code base.

Comment: beat me to it. that is how it should be. alternatively just adding the String in an already sorted format which is ok if there is no need to reuse it later.

Comment: I am not 100% what you are trying to say (I read: you would have written a similar answer). Nut sure about the last sentence though ;-)

Comment: as you suggested the right way of doing it, is to model the String by giving it a certain semantics (e.g. <5 is less than <10 and so on). it can be a very difficult task, but say if you trying to show a certain set of options in a webpage, it probably be easier to just show them in a sorted format of course by sacrificing re-usability.

Comment: btw by re-usability I meant that you can't change options from <5 to <3 in a dynamic way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use streams like this:

```
testList = testList.stream()
    .sorted((one,another)->one.getCode().compareTo(another.getCode()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```